# Acceleration of block-incline system if BOTH can move freely (and no friction)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram

My AP Physics teacher posed a challenge question to us:

> If a block slides down a frictionless incline that rests on a frictionless table AND the incline is not fixed in place, express the acceleration of the block-incline system in terms of the mass of the block, the mass of the incline, the angle of the incline, and gravity.

I can express the acceleration of the block easily enough ($mg\sin(\theta)$) but I have no clue what the block does to the ramp. I'm *guessing* that the horizontal component of the normal force would push the ramp in the opposite horizontal direction of the block.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Drawing the free body diagram is *always* a good idea. But I urge you to try and do the experiment and watch what happens. Sure, you can't totally eliminate friction, but if you put a heavy ball (like a bowling ball) onto a wedge that's sitting on a skateboard, it'll give you a pretty good idea. Another option is to use a wedge of ice on a smooth tabletop.

Comment: Hi there! Nice problem. Is the plane freely falling?

Comment: Hi! Ok PM 2 Ring, I will try the experiment when I get home! And no Deschele, the plane is lying on a frictionless table, but is not fixed in place.

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework-help / check-my-work site

Comment: Removed a number of rude comments. Please keep it nice, and don't repost comments that have been removed.

Comment: Chris, it wasn’t homework. I was trying to explain that to BioPhys.

Comment: @Overwhelmed I understand it wasn't explicitly assigned "homework". I was speaking more generally as to the type of post/question. You can look at the links in the close banner for more information. I apologize if I was coming across as rude or unhelpful; I think it is more helpful to point out how the site works to help users with future posts.

Answer (score 1):

> I can express the acceleration of the block easily enough (mgsin(θ))

Careful. That's the acceleration of the block along the incline. Since the incline will also move, the block also has an acceleration component perpendicular to the incline.

Draw a FBD. Normal force is important here.

You should decompose the forces acting on the block in the parallel/perpendicular to incline directions. The forces acting on the incline should be broken down in the usually $xy$ directions.

---

I started the FBD process for you. I have not labeled the forces -- that's for you to do :)

[image]

Remember:

- $a_{x, \ \rm block}\neq 0$
- $a_{y, \ \rm block}\neq 0$
- $a_{X, \ \rm incline}\neq 0$
- $a_{Y, \ \rm incline}= 0$

Comment: Okay I've drawn the FBD to the best of my ability... I have strange results. My forces are as follows:

Normal force perpendicular to the incline, the "horizontal" (tilted axis to match incline) component of mg (mgsin(theta)).

The horizontal component of the normal force that acts on the incline itself (standard axes) which I found to be mgcos(theta)sin(theta).

And then... using Newton's third law + some more trig I would have another "horizontal" force for the block down the incline which is mgcos^2(theta)sin(theta)... Does this sound right? Oh, and mg pointed down of course.

Comment: *The horizontal component of the normal force that acts on the incline itself (standard axes) which I found to be mgcos(theta)sin(theta)* I'm not sure that's right. To get that, you'd have to assume that $m_\mathrm{block} a_\perp = N-mg\cos\theta=0$ which is false, since $a_\perp\neq 0$. You'd need a system of equations to solve for the normal $N$.

Comment: Took me a minute to understand what you mean, but I think I got it. N cannot be equal to mgcos(theta). It must be less because the incline is accelerating in the negative x direction. Similar to an elevator accelerating downward. So then, I would set N - mgcos(theta) equal to... *something* so that I can solve for N?

Comment: It would help if you posted a picture of your FBD

Comment: but $N-mg\cos\theta=ma_\perp$ where $a_\perp$ is the component of acceleration perpendicular to the incline

Comment: also if you could label your axes, that would help us communicate

Comment: @Overwhelmed I included semi-complete FBD for you. This should help.

Comment: Sorry for just now responding. I was able to set up a system of 3 equations from this information, and then solved for N, A (incline), and a (block down incline) in terms of m, M (incline), g, and θ. It is... messy, so I ended up typing it into Wolfram Alpha to see if it could be cleaned up a bit. Still messy, but I will show you what I got for each.

Comment: Answers to questions like these really should just include relevant concepts rather than partially worked solutions.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean, but sometimes trying to work out solutions helps me in understanding the concepts behind them. My math/numbers intuition tends to be greater than my conceptual intuition.

Comment: @Overwhelmed I completely understand. I am a tutor myself and I love helping people work out physics problems. I meant no disrespect; it is just that PSE is not the site for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

If the block (mass, m) is sliding down the incline (mass, M) to the right (with positive, x, horizontal to the right),  then the horizontal component of the normal force from the block accelerates the incline in the negative x direction: - Nsin(θ) = MA  (where θ is the angle of the incline from the horizontal.)  The reaction force accelerates the block to the right:  Nsin(θ) = m$a_x$ = m(A + $a_x$') = m(A + a'cos(θ))  (where, a, is in the inertial frame and, a' , is measured relative to the surface of the incline).  In the vertical direction, (taking positive, y, down) gravity acts on the block:  mg – Ncos(θ) = m$a_y$ =   m$a_y$' = ma'sin(θ).  This gives three equations with three unknowns: N, A, and a'.